# Use Activity functions in no activity class

Tags: android

it is probably an noob question but still. I need to my main activity class will use other class to do some code. This class uses function that are from Activity like getPackageName(), new Intent etc.
So I need some help with this, for example what I need it to setContentView via class. How do I do this?

Main Acticity:
    package com.example.testapp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        SetContentView cn = new SetContentView();
        cn.MySetContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

SetViewClass:
        package com.example.testapp;

```
    public class SetContentView
    {
        void MySetContentView(int activityMain)
        {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //no set content view if not activity
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit. Why do you want to do this? It doesn't make sense to set content view from outside the `Activity` for instance. If you explain why you want to do this, there might be a simple solution for you instead of "hacking and slashing" the API completely.
Also, you can call `getPackageName` from the `Application` class, which you can subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right, you could try having a root class extending `Activity` and holding your methods, and then extending it in `MainActivity`:

```
    public class Helper extends Activity {
    ... // your methods, e.g. MySetContentView
    }
```

and then:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Helper {
    ... // any call to methods in Helper
    }
```

This can be useful if you have a lot of activities that share the same code - you can have them all extending the same `Helper` class, and still being Activities.

In your case:

```
    public class Helper extends Activity {
        public void mySetContentView(int layout) {
               setContentView(layout)
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Helper {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mySetContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static MainActivity instance;

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
          return instance;
    }   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance=this;
    }
}
public class OtherClass 
{
   protected void someMethod() {
      MainActivity ma= MainActivity.getInstance();
     //use ma methods... 
   }
}
```